# Opening a file using a specific program doesn't produce output

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

First of all, I am new to coding, and I have looked for similar questions and I know some commands which can be used in Python and in CMD to open a file using an executable. The problem I'm having is that when I try to use those commands, the program runs without any error, but it doesn't give the output file that should give. On the other hand, when I just double click the file, which is set to open with `*.exe`, it works and produces the output.
I tried the CMD command:

```
start "path of .exe" "filepath"
```

also just:

```
"path of .exe" "filepath"
```

Then I tried the os and subprocess modules in python:

```
subprocess.Popen(...)
os.system(...)
subprocess.run(...)
```

and many other solution I found on the internet. The point is that all of these solution don't give errors and should work, but they don't produce the wanted file for me. I used the same commands on another file with a different `.exe` and they work.
This is the step that is not working in my attempt to automate a whole process. If someone is willing to take a look at the files, you can download them from the following link:

https://gofile.io/?c=5TJtS9

The files are as follows:
1. running the `rdam.grd` file with `hist_dam2d.exe` produces the `hist.plotps` file
2. then running the `hist.plotps` with `plotps.exe` produces the wanted diagram

It should be an easy task that doesn't work for me.

For more information... This is part a random finite element software which is freely distributed by the authors. You can see the whole documentation and download all parts of the program from this link:
http://random.engmath.dal.ca/rfem/
The parts that are causing the problem are used just for extracting and showing results.
It is an old software so maybe there is some problem with that.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the exact commands you are using. Even a small typo in parameters can result in an error.

Comment: As I said there were no errors, all the commands were executed just fine but generated no output. However I'll try to recheck all the commands and will update the question..

Comment: It's `Start "optional title between these doublequotes" "p:\ath to\myapp.exe" args` not `start "path of .exe" "filepath"` Note: the title between the doublequotes is optional, the doublequotes aren't, _they're required_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you did with your Python code since you didn't provide the exact code snippets. I also don't have the reputation to comment. So I'll just provide code examples for the 3 methods you listed (CMD, Powershell, Python). All three methods worked on my machine.
1) CMD

```
start "" "plotps.exe" hist.plotps
```

The double quotes after the start keyword are there to specify an optional title. What went wrong in your CMD example is that windows thought "plotps.exe" was the title. You don't need to specify a title, but you need to write the quotes. More info on this keyword can be found here: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html
Also note that start is asynchronous
A synchronous way of doing it would be:

```
plotps.exe hist.plotps
```

2) Powershell

```
Start-Process -FilePath "plotps.exe" -ArgumentList "hist.plotps"
```

I would **strongly** recommend using powershell over CMD if you have access to both.
This method is synchronous.
More info on Start-Process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-5.0

3) Python
I'm not a python expert but this worked for me:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['plotps.exe', 'hist.plotps'])
```